# Laravel Relationship: Belongtomany and wherein

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

I have 2 tables, there's a belong to many relationship between them with a pivot table.
I'm trying to get a query of the first table with an array of ids on the second table.

Example:
TableA: ID: 1, 2, 3
TableB: ID: 1, 2, 3

Pivot Table:

ID_tableA: 1, 1, 2, 3
ID_tableB: 1, 2, 2, 3

I must fetch a Table A when both id 1 and 2 of table B are related in the pivot table.
Example:

```
TableA::whereHas('tableB', fn($q)=>$q->magicQueryPleaseHelp([1, 2]))->get();
```

Should return only TableA with id 1.

I've tried using `whereIn('id', [1,2])` inside the whereHas but it fetches out TableA with id 2 too.
Using many whereHas on each of the array items give the desire result but it's too weird.

There's a more adequate solution?

Comment: `whereIn()` takes 2 parameters, the column and values, so it _should_ be `$q->whereIn('tableB.id', [1, 2]);`

Comment: `whereIn('id', ...)` also won't work, as you're joining 3 tables, `TableA`, `TableB` and the pivot table, so it doesn't know which `id` you're trying to reference via `id`; that's why my comment said `tableB.id`, but change as needed.